# Change image when touched

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sprite-kit, uitouch

I need an image to change itself when it's touched.

At the moment the image that changes is the next image that spawns and not self.

```
@implementation MyScene2
{
    Marsugo *marsugo;
    SKAction *actionMoveDown;
    SKAction *actionMoveEnded;
    SKTexture *rescued;

}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        // Initializes Background
        self.currentBackground = [Background generateNewBackground];
        [self addChild:self.currentBackground];


    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {

        NSArray *nodes = [self nodesAtPoint:[touch locationInNode:self]];

        for (SKNode *node in nodes) {
            if ([node.name isEqualToString:playerObject]) {

                rescued = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"rescued"];
                marsugo.texture = rescued;

       // this is changing the image of the next marsugo that spawns instead of self.         
            }
        }
    }
}

-(void)addMarsugos
{
// the marsugo is being initialized inside this method, that might be the issue i believe
    // Create sprite
    marsugo = [[Marsugo alloc]init];
    marsugo.xScale = 0.3;
    marsugo.yScale = 0.3;
    marsugo.zPosition = 75;

    // Bounds + Spawn Positions
    int minX = marsugo.size.width;
    int maxX = self.frame.size.width - marsugo.size.width;
    int rangeX = maxX - minX;
    int actualX = (arc4random() % rangeX) + minX;
    marsugo.position = CGPointMake(actualX, self.frame.size.height + 50);
    [self addChild:marsugo];

    // Spawn Timer
    int minDuration = 1;
    int maxDuration = 10;
    int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
    int actualDuration = (arc4random() % rangeDuration) + minDuration;

    // Movement Actions
    actionMoveDown = [SKAction moveTo:CGPointMake(actualX, CGRectGetMinY(self.frame)) duration:actualDuration];
    actionMoveEnded = [SKAction removeFromParent];
    [marsugo runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMoveDown, actionMoveEnded]]];

    NSLog(@"Marsugo X: %f - Speed: %i", marsugo.position.x, actualDuration);
}


@end
```

Like i said previously, i need the self sprite to change texture and not the "next spawning sprite".

Any help fixing this would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use touchesBegan - you're better off using a tap gesture recognizer. Below I have _testView, which is an instance variable I create and add to the view in viewDidLoad. I then created a tap gesture recognizer that calls a function when the view is tapped, and that function changes the color of the view - but in your case you can call your function that changes the image:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // create the test view and add it as a subview
    _testView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 100, 100)];
    _testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_testView];

    // create the tap gesture recognizer and add it to the test view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeColor)];
    [_testView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

- (void)changeColor {
    // here I'm changing the color, but you can do whatever you need once the tap is recognized
    _testView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
}
```

This results in this at first:

[image]

Then when I tap the view:

[image]

Comment: my SKScene has no view did load

Comment: What is SKScene a subclass of?

Comment: Then better option is to override `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` as mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` in your `Marsugo` class and change the texture there. That way, you won't have to check if the touch is inside your node because that method won't be called if it's not.